# How would I remove a row in a table every five seconds using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How would I go about removing a table row every 5 seconds in Javascript. The error that constantly pops up in my console refers to an undefined parentNode but I'm trying to define the parent of the 'td' tags with this second line of code.

```
function removeTableRows () {
    var studentTable = document.getElementsByTagName("td").parentNode;
    studentTable.parentNode.removeChild(studentTable);

     setTimeout (removeTableRows, 5000);  
    }


    removeTableRows();
```

Comment: `var studentTable = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].parentNode;`

Comment: @dandavis worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function removeTableRows () {
    var studentTable = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].parentNode;
    studentTable.parentNode.removeChild(studentTable);

     setInterval (removeTableRows, 5000);  
    }


    removeTableRows();
```

EDIT:

1)"document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].parentNode".This part of the code solves the problem.

2)The document.getElementsByTagName("td") fetches an HTML Collection and so hence we have to specific before deleting the node.

Comment: Anything you'd like to mention? Like what part of this code solves the OP's problem? Or any further information/links that you can provide on the subject matter?

Comment: Please post these points as edits to your answers and then delete these comments.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
function removeTableRows () {
    var studentTable = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].parentNode;
    studentTable.parentNode.removeChild(studentTable);         
}
setTimeout (removeTableRows, 5000);
```